# Android App soft keyboard covers web page's textarea embedded in webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have an Android app which opens a website inside its web view that is embedded inside a fragment, the fragment is controlled by a bottom navigation bar. The app is not running in full screen mode. I have action tool bar on the top of web view.

The web page inside webview works fine.

However, the problem is if the web page contains a `<textarea>`, when user start typing the content inside Android pops up its soft keyboard which covers the Textarea, that makes the user unable to see what has been typed inside.

I have done a lot google search and tried with setting things like in AndroidManifest.xml file add the attribute:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Or in my fragment Java code I put the following:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Or I even tried in the web page I put the following javascript:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="100" v-model="message" ref="message" onfocus="this.scrollIntoView();"></textarea>
```

But none of these resolve my problem. Could you please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It turns out it is the bottom navigation bar that covered html `<textarea>`. Android OS does push the webview up when keyboard is displayed (It only shows the first line of `<textarea>` though). However, since I have navigation tab bar under the webview, it blocked the first line of `<textarea>` so `<textarea>` inside of my webview becomes completely invisible.

The fix is to add the following to my fragment.xml

```
android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```